# Adding a field, for example IndemnificationAmount to a product in uCommerce Store/Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

I have a problem in Umbraco/uCommerce.

I'm trying to find a way of adapting uCommerce Store  for my specific needs. What I'm aiming to do is add an indemnification amount to an insurance product, but can't seem to figure it out.

Edit:
On the product page I want to have a field where you can input a number (the indemnification amount) which will be used to present the insurance premium via some service (not realy import for the question). When the amount is entered and the customer is happy with the premium and adds the product to the basket, I want the product property (indemnification amount) to be populated and the product added to the basket...

Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add the product to your basket with [CommerceLibrary:AddToBasket()](http://ucommerce.dk/docs/html/M_UCommerce_Xslt_TransactionLibrary_AddToBasket.htm)

Then add a dynamic order property to the line created with AddToBasket(). You can set them on the order itself or individual order lines.

In XSLT you use [CommerceLibrary:SetOrderProperty("myProp", "myValue")](http://www.ucommerce.dk/docs/html/M_UCommerce_Xslt_TransactionLibrary_SetOrderProperty_1.htm) or [SetOrderPorperty(lineIndex, "myProp", "myValue")](http://www.ucommerce.dk/docs/html/M_UCommerce_Xslt_TransactionLibrary_SetOrderProperty.htm).

In .NET you use myOrder["myProp"] = "myValue or myOrderLine["myProp"] = "myValue".

Comment: A dynamic order line property is the way to go. You just grab the value you want to store and use the outlined method to store it with the propery order line.

Comment: Hi again, sorry for being a pain, just new to Umbraco. I can't seem to get a grip of exactly how to implement it.. Would much appreciate a little bit longer explanation..

Comment: I'm getting there (slowly), how do you get the lineindex? Can't seem to find what is returned from the addtobasket method. Otherwise I'm guessing the latest item added to the basket is in the end of the list..

Comment: You can find index as part of XML returned by the GetBasket() call. The XML returned from the AddToBasket method will only contain information on whether the operation was successful.